# Popup not working and no errors

Tags: ionic2

Popup.alert is not working using "ionic-framework: 2.0.0-alpha.42".

I am using "ionic-framework: 2.0.0-alpha.42" locally and "ionic@2.0.0-beta.15" globally in NPM.

Using this [document](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/2.0.0-alpha.42/api/components/popup/Popup/) as an example.

```
this.popup.alert({
    title: "New Friend!",
    template: "Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!",
    cssClass: 'my-alert'
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Alert closed');
});
```

That code is not working. I do not see a popup and i do not see "Alert closed" ever shown in the console. I pull in "popup" through the constructor.

```
private popup: Popup;
constructor(popup: Popup) {
    this.popup = popup;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. You need to add

`<ion-overlay></ion-overlay>`

to your app.html. I saw that no where in the documentation.

Comment: I had to wait a couple days to be able to Mark it as answered.